# namespacing functions in php

Tags: php, function, namespaces

I am having trouble with namespaces and functions. I'm using php 7.

I have a file:

```
namespace profordable\app;

function get_app() {
    if (!class_exists('profordable\app\app')) {
        return false;
    }
    global $global;
    if (!isset($$global)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $$global;
}

class app {
    ...
}
```

and my main index file:

```
namespace profordable\app;
$global = 'app';
$app = new app;
```

and another file as FILE (global namespace):

```
function some_function() {
    $app = get_app();
}
```

I can't seem to fetch the get_app function in FILE, I've tested it and...

```
var_dump(function_exists('profordable\app\get_app');
```

returns true, but when I try combinations of (in FILE)...

```
use profordable\app;
use function profordable\app\get_app;
function some_function() {
    $app = get_app();
    $app = profordable\app\get_app();
    $app = \get_app();
    ...etc
}
```

it doesn't work. please help

Comment: What does it do or not do? What is the error(s)?

Comment: no error, get_app() just returns null

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick in FILE:

```
use function profordable\app\get_app as get_app;
```